# Securing firebase table that multiple users need to write to

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a firebase realtime database with the following structure:

```
users:
  user_id:
    name: str
    friend_ids: [str]
records:
  record_id:
    text: str
```

I'm now trying to secure that database to minimize the probability that nefarious users will delete or overwrite information of value in the db. If each user could only write to their record in the users table, I believe I could secure the data with a Firebase rule like:

```
"users": {
  "$uid": {
    ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
  }
}
```

However, each user also needs to be able to write to other users' records, so that e.g. user A can become friends with user B and can update the `friend_ids` attributes of both user A and B atomically.

My question is: how should I go about securing a database with this setup? Each user needs to be able to write to any user_id and any record_id. Any recommendations others can offer on this question would be super helpful!

Comment: *"Each user needs to be able to write to any user_id"* - that directly conflicts with what you said in the previous paragraph about friends.  Assuming that you didn't mean to say exactly this, what you'll have to do is use the contents of your database that expresses the relationships between the users, and query it in the rules to make sure the required conditions are met for a given write operation. See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security#section-revisiting-advanced-example

Comment: It seems the desired approach would be to store an attribute in registered users' records in the user table then use some attribute based security rules: https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#attribute-based_and_role-based_access

Comment: @DougStevenson (pleasure to meet another Doug!) thanks for your note. Yes, I think I need something like the attribute based authentication in the firebase docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#data-defined_attributes_and_roles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want any user to be able to write their own UID in somebody's else's friend list, as long as they also write that other person's UID in their own friend list at the same time.

If that's the case, it'd be:

```
"friends": {
  "$uid1": {
    "$uid2": {
      ".write": "$uid1 === auth.uid && 
        newData.parent().parent().child($uid2).child(auth.uid).exists"
    }
  }
}
```

For simplicity's sake I wrote the check as if the `friends` node is at the top-level here. I'd actually recommend doing that anyway, as it's best to [model flat lists](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#flatten_data_structures) in Firebase, and not nest entity types.